# Microsoft VS Code not showing MFA code when logging into WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-extensions, multi-factor-authentication

I have VS code and WSL also installed in the system. When logging onto AWS CLI using WSL-> Ubuntu after authentication, it asks to authenticate using the MFA code displayed on the Ubuntu terminal. But when using VS Code to login to AWS CLI even it asks for MFA authentication but it doesn't show MFA code. I have shown the Ubuntu screenshot and VS code screenshot below.[As you can see in the image, MFA code in not showing in the VS code terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SZVE.png)